# Pass data from database to ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website which is developed in ASP.NET and backbend is C#. I am dynamically trying to pass the value from the Database to the header. I can do this for the user name by simply doing `<%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName() %>` and that will return the correct user name. How would I do this for a course name?

Below is my code which reads the values from the DB

```
public DataTable GetCourseData()
{
    string UsrName = User.Identity.Name;
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CourseName FROM Course WHERE UserName=@UserName"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                SqlParameter para2 = new SqlParameter("UserName", UsrName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(para2);
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt.Tables[0];
}
```

If I do `<%: GetCourseData() %>` it doesn't return the course.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the Question? GetCourseData returns a DataTable. That ToString likely returns some nice text - namely "DataTable" unless I am mistaken (type is the default ToString). Antipatterns again - try making this an object and then grab the right field.

Comment: I want to get the course name and display it on the page

Comment: You want a `string` instead of the `DataTable`?

Comment: @mot Yes, that's exactly what I am after

Comment: So the question is: _Is there anyone that can code this piece for me?_

Comment: @MelanciaUK No I will code it myself! I just wanted a suggestion whether this can be achieved or not and is this the right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is you return a `DataTable` which describes a whole table with your query results. You probably want to get the data you need from it, like so:

```
return dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CourseName"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have completely changed my method to return a string and got it to work. However your solution is also helpful so I will accept it.